# Jump to file and line from outside XCode 4.2

Tags: xcode, xcode4, applescript, xcode4.2, developer-tools

For the NSLogger project we would like to implement the feature to directly jump back to XCode to the line in the file that issued the log entry. One would expect thatthis would be easy using the command line tool like this:

```
xed --line 100 ~/work/xyz/MainWindowController.m
```

But this results in an unexpected error:

> 2011-10-31 17:37:36.159 xed[53507:707] Error: Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-1728 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (OSStatus error -1728.)" (e.g.,: specifier asked for the
>   3rd, but there are only 2. Basically, this indicates a run-time
>   resolution error. ) UserInfo=0x40043dc20 {ErrorNumber=-1728,
>   ErrorOffendingObject=}

Another idea is to use AppleScript to tell XCode to do the desired steps, but I was not able to find a working solution.

So any solution to reach the desired effect would be very appreciated.

Reference to the NSLogger Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/issues/30

Comment: Same problem here. I reported a bug to Apple: rdar://10626303 - see a copy of it on OpenRadar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1480404

Comment: Problem similar with the xed version in /usr/bin and in /Developer/usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

The `xed` tool seems to be working fine:

```
xed --line 100 /Users/Anne/Desktop/Test/TestAppDelegate.m
```

**Error**

> e.g.,: specifier asked for the 3rd, but there are only 2

The error above simply indicates that the requested line is out of range.

**Solution**

Check wether the line number actually exists before executing `xed`.

**Quickly written example**

```
// Define file and line number
NSString *filePath = @"/Users/Anne/Desktop/Test/TestAppDelegate.m"; 
int theLine = 100;

// Count lines in file
NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
unsigned numberOfLines, index, stringLength = [fileContent length];
for (index = 0, numberOfLines = 0; index < stringLength; numberOfLines++)
    index = NSMaxRange([fileContent lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(index, 0)]);

// The requested line does not exist
if (theLine > numberOfLines) {
    NSLog(@"Error: The requested line is out of range.");

// The requested line exists
} else {

    // Run xed through AppleScript or NSTask
    NSString *theSource = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"do shell script \"xed --line %d \" & quoted form of \"%@\"", theLine, filePath];        
    NSAppleScript *theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:theSource];
    [theScript executeAndReturnError:nil];

}
```

**Note**

Make sure to count the number of lines correctly:
[Counting Lines of Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great example an I learned a lot from it. But it doesn't seem to work for Xcode 4 on my machine. It opens the file but does not jump to the line specified. My setup is Lion 10.7.2, Xcode 4.2.